# Material-UI / ReactJS - Open Nested List based on URL

Tags: reactjs, routes, material-ui, nested-lists

I am using ReactJS with Material-UI. How can I make the MUI [nested list](https://material-ui.com/components/lists/#nested-list) open certain items based on the URL? In the code example below, if somebody is on /inbox/starred/ then I would like Inbox to be open and Starred to be active. I played around with React Router Nested Routes but I wasn't able to figure it out.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import ListSubheader from '@material-ui/core/ListSubheader';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import DraftsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Drafts';
import SendIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Send';
import ExpandLess from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandLess';
import ExpandMore from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import StarBorder from '@material-ui/icons/StarBorder';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: 360,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
  nested: {
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing(4),
  },
}));

export default function NestedList() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <List
      component="nav"
      aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
      subheader={
        <ListSubheader component="div" id="nested-list-subheader">
          Nested List Items
        </ListSubheader>
      }
      className={classes.root}
    >
      <ListItem button>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <SendIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Sent mail" />
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem button>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <DraftsIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Drafts" />
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem button onClick={handleClick}>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <InboxIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Inbox" />
        {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
      </ListItem>
      <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <List component="div" disablePadding>
          <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <StarBorder />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Starred" />
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </Collapse>
    </List>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this task, I'd recommend using `react-router`'s URL param.

First, you'd need to change your route into something like this:

```
<Route path="/:drawer/:subDrawer" children={<NestedList />} />
```

Notice `:drawer` and `:subDrawer` in the above path. That's what we're going to use to know what route we're at.

Then, in your component, use `drawer` and `subDrawer` from the URL params like so (for demonstration purposes, I hid some stuff, but you get the idea):

```
// ...other imports
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function NestedList() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  
  const { drawer, subDrawer } = useParams();
  
  return (
    <List>
      {//... other stuff}

      <ListItem button onClick={handleClick}>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <InboxIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Inbox" />
        {// changed the logic here}
        {drawer === 'inbox' ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
      </ListItem>
      <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <List component="div" disablePadding>
          {// changed the logic here}
          <ListItem
            selected={subDrawer === 'starred'}
            button className={classes.nested}
          >
            <ListItemIcon>
              <StarBorder />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Starred" />
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </Collapse>
    </List>
  );
}
```

Now, since we're depending on the route to know which drawer is opened, we should change `onClick` for each menu item to redirect the user to the appropriate route. Maybe when the user clicks on `Sent mail`, The page will get redirected to `/sent-mail` and the corresponding button for Sent mail would look like this:

```
      <ListItem button selected={subDrawer === 'sent-item'}>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <SendIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Sent mail" />
      </ListItem>
```

and so on...

Comment: thank you. I was able to get it to work using location.pathname.startsWith('/Sent/')